# vuetify не отрабатывает выбор даты в v-data-picker на typescript на основе классов

Tags: typescript, vuetify

имеется компонент, со скпритом на typescript, который работает нормально:

```
  <template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
      <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        v-model="menu"
        :nudge-right="40"
        :return-value.sync="date"
        lazy
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        full-width
        min-width="290px"
      >
        <v-text-field
          slot="activator"
          v-model="date"
          label="Picker in menu"
          prepend-icon="event"
          readonly
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title scrollable>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
        </v-date-picker>
      </v-menu>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  data () {
    return {
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      menu: false,
      modal: false
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

есть скрипт написать на основе класса, то выбор даты не срабатывает ...

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

export default class Budget extends Vue {
  date: string = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)
  menu: boolean = false
  modal: boolean = false
}
</script>
```

подскажите в чем может быть причина?!

спасибо

Answer (score 0):

в код просто добавил:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
  components: {

    }
})

export default class Budget extends Vue {
  date: string = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)
  menu: boolean = false
  modal: boolean = false
}
</script>
```

и оно заработало нормально...